# How do I create comment-reply-button using <span> element not <a>

Tags: php, functions, comments

I'm currently working to design my first WordPress blog and I got stuck when I came to code comment-reply-button because I want the comment-reply-button to be coded in **span** element only not **a** element at all. I know it's possible because I saw this on some blog:

[image]

It works. But, I tried my level best but could not make a working one. Will you experts please help me out! I'm mentioning the **custom callback** I'm using for comment system, please have a glance over them and give me a solution.

```
function comment($comment, $args, $depth) {$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
<div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
<div class="comment-author">
<cite class="fn"><?php printf(__('%s'), get_comment_author_link()) ?></cite>
</div>
<?php comment_text(); ?>
<div class="comment-reply">

**** HERE <SPAN> ELEMENT FOR REPLY-BUTTON WILL BE PLACED ****

</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Here's the custom comment form for reply as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a custom comment reply element like so:

*This will replace the `**** HERE <SPAN> ELEMENT FOR REPLY-BUTTON WILL BE PLACED ****`.*

```
<?php if ( get_option( 'comment_registration' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-login" href="<?php // wrapped
      echo esc_url( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?>">Log in to Reply</a>
<?php else : // User is logged-in or that registration not needed to comment.
// 'respond' is the ID of the comment form's wrapper.
$onclick = sprintf( 'return addComment.moveForm( "%s", "%d", "respond", "%d" )',
    'div-comment-' . $comment->comment_ID, $comment->comment_ID, get_the_ID() ); ?>
    <span class="btn btn-rwr"
      data-href="#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" onclick='<?php echo $onclick; ?>'
      aria-label="Reply to <?php echo esc_attr( $comment->comment_author ); ?>">Reply</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `span` markup is *identical* to the one in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW6Qj.png). But you can change it easily..

### UPDATE

*If nothing happens* when you click on the custom `span` element, then make sure the comment reply (JavaScript) script is loaded: ***(add this code to the theme's `functions.php` file)***

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
} );
```

And make sure the `respond` below is the correct ID of the comment form's **wrapper**:

```
$onclick = sprintf( 'return addComment.moveForm( "%s", "%d", "respond", "%d" )'
```

And in your CSS, you can also add something like:

```
.comment-reply > span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

### UPDATE #2

For the default `comment-reply` script (check previous update) to work as expected, in your comment `<li>`, `.comment-reply` should be placed *below/after* **and not inside** the `.comment-body`:

```
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
        ...
    </div><!-- .comment-body -->
    <div class="comment-reply">
        ...the SPAN here..
    </div>
</li>
```

And in your CSS, you should have something like:

```
#respond + .comment-reply {
    display: none;
}
```

to hide the "Reply" `span`/button after its clicked.

Comment: I did tried this code snippet on my callback as reply button but it's not working because it is not clickable.

Comment: What do you mean not clickable? Did you see any JS errors in the browser's console? And when you inspect the element, it's the markup you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: See the "UPDATE" part in the answer and let me know.

Comment: Sorry Sally, I brought you to this unwanted trouble. Well, this span code will only work with a custom comment reply form that comes up once someone click over this reply button. Do me one more favoue, please code one for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Have you just tried to enqueue the comment reply script? And if you look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW6Qj.png), it has `addComment.moveForm()`; so what else do you expect? What is the ID of the comment form's wrapper? You should replace it with the `respond` in the code (i.e. `addComment.moveForm()`).

Comment: I tried everything you said but it is not working. There is a reason, I am editing the question, just look at it, everything will get clearer

Comment: There is a custom reply-form with reply button as well that appears when someone clicks over that span element.

Comment: What is the theme you're using? Name and the URL.

Comment: I am creating a custom theme taking neilpatel.com's theme as an inspiration. I am designing on localhost otherwise I would have let you know my site url to inspect.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I hope the update helps.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for helping me from the beginning to the conclusion. I am obliged.

Comment: You can accept the answer. :) (we both gain some rep and people also know the question has a solution that worked)