# How do I make comment-reply-button with <span> that takes to comment reply form on click

Tags: php, functions, javascript, comment-form

I do need your help. I'm actually designing my personal blog's theme and I got stuck when I could not code a working comment-reply-button with *span* element.

I know you must be wondering why with a *span* element when a person can easily use simple php command to get *comment_reply_link* in WordPress. Let me clear it, I am quite obsessed with perfectionism. Well, I am taking neilpatel.com's blog template as my inspiration theme.

While designing my blog's comment system I saw he used span element for comment-reply-button so I too desired to do the same, I tried but could not make it happen. Please help me out. His code was like this:

[image]

Here he used *span* element for reply button and when someone clicks over this button, it takes to a custom comment-reply form hidden just below the same comment that person is willing to reply.

I also tried and coded a markup something like this:

```
<?php if ( get_option( 'comment_registration' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-login" href="<?php // wrapped
  echo esc_url( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?>">Log in to Reply</a>
<?php else : // User is logged-in or that registration not needed to comment.
// 'respond' is the ID of the comment form's wrapper.
$onclick = sprintf( 'return addComment.moveForm( "%s", "%d", "respond", "%d" )',
'div-comment-' . $comment->comment_ID, $comment->comment_ID, get_the_ID() ); ?>
<span class="btn btn-rwr"
  data-href="#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" onclick='<?php echo $onclick; ?>'
  aria-label="Reply to <?php echo esc_attr( $comment->comment_author ); ?>">Reply</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this code was not taking me to comment-reply form on click because I was unable to code a custom reply form and JavaScript for it. Please help me out. I seiously desire to have my blog's comment-reply system to work like neilpatel.com's blog comment-reply system.

For more details and better understanding, you can look at neilpatel.com's blog comment system. I know you understood what I meant(you will have better understanding of what I am saying).

Here is my comments.php file:

```
<h3 class="title">Comments (<span class="color medium"><?php echo get_comments_number();?></span>)</h3><ol><?php wp_list_comments('style=ol&callback=comment'); ?></ol><?php comment_form(); ?>
```

And, here comes my current custom callback for comments:

```
function comment($comment, $args, $depth) {$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
<div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
<div class="comment-author"><cite class="fn"><?php printf(__('%s'), get_comment_author_link()) ?></cite></div>
<?php comment_text(); ?></div>
<div class="reply">
<?php if ( get_option( 'comment_registration' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-login" href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?>">Log in to Reply</a><?php else :  $onclick = sprintf( 'return addComment.moveForm( "%s", "%d", "respond", "%d" )', 'div-comment-' . $comment->comment_ID, $comment->comment_ID, get_the_ID() ); ?><span class="reply-btn" data-href="#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" onclick='<?php echo $onclick; ?>' aria-label="Reply to <?php echo esc_attr( $comment->comment_author ); ?>">Reply</span><?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php }
```

Please help... I do need it...

Comment: I thought you already had this working properly before? What exactly is still not working? Can you show your `comments.php` template code?

Comment: I don't know you'll understand me or not but you should at least go to neilpatel.com's blog as see what I am trying to say. The span element markup you told also requires a custom comment-reply-form just below every comment that opens on click. I was  unable to make one so I just put the question again

Comment: I posted that comment after I visited one of the blog posts on NeilPatel.com. So I suggest you to add to your question the code in your `comments.php` template. But if you want to modify the comment form's markup (HTML), you can use the various hooks fired in the [`comment_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) function. The code that I gave you, I have tested it to work just fine on the Twenty Nineteen theme.

Comment: Sorry Sally for misunderstanding you! I have mentioned both comments.php file and custom callback for comments, I am currently using. Please help me out now!  don't just know how will I do this but I know you could make this really work.

Comment: Please post the actual code and not screenshot of the code. And is that the *whole* code in your `comments.php` template?

Comment: Have edited the question and mentioned code.

Comment: Yes, this is the whole code in my comments.php file.

Comment: Sally, are you there to help me out? Please do this favor to me.... I beg.

Comment: Your `comment()` callback works fine for me. So the problem is most likely because you are *not* loading the `comment-reply.js` script - via the `functions.php` file of your theme; although on NeilPatel.com, the script is minified in [this](https://neilpatel-qvjnwj7eutn3.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/neilpatel/js/script-singular.js?ver=2.0.2018.12.18.7) file - just search for "`moveForm:function`".

Comment: Yes Sally, you're right it was not working just because comment-reply-script was not loading through functions.php. I copied the minified script and copied to the comment section and it worked. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. But I wouldn't copy that file.. because WordPress indeed comes with that script. You just need to enqueue it - you can check the code [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/321927/137402). Nonetheless, use whatever works best for you.

Comment: PS: I suggest you to just *delete* the other [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/323364/137402).